# Preview image before its uploaded using vuetify "<v-file-input>"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

This is what I have right now

```
      <v-file-input
            v-model="image"
            type="file"
            class="input"
            label="Upload license"
            hint="Add a picture of youre license"
            outlined
            dense
            @change="onFileChange"
          />

          <v-img :src="image" />
```

Just so you know, I know how to do this with the  "", it kinda looks like this:

```
createImage (file) {
  const image = new Image()
  const reader = new FileReader()
  const vm = this

  reader.onload = (e) => {
    vm.image = e.target.result
    console.log(vm.image)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
   },        
 onFileChange (e) {
  const files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files
  if (!files.length) { return }
  this.createImage(files[0])
},
```

and just call to onFileChange on the input tag like @change="onFileChange"

Comment: can you add `createImage` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<v-file-input>` returns the file(s) itself on `@change` event unlike the native `<input type="file" />`. So in that case `e.target.files` does not exist there, `e` is the file itself. Also I would recommend not to share `image` for both `v-file-input` and `v-img`. `v-img` expects an url and `v-file-input` expects a file. Instead, I would recommend splitting it to 2 different variables like `image` and `imageUrl`.

Below you can see an example:

```html
<v-file-input v-model="image" outlined dense @change="onFileChange" />
<v-img :src="imageUrl" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    image: undefined,
    // to save image url
    imageUrl: ""
  };
},
methods: {
  createImage(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = e => {
      this.imageUrl = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  },
  onFileChange(file) {
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }
    this.createImage(file);
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/onelly/pen/xxOBJjL

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're doing right. You've created object url on `this.url`, so you should use it instead of `image` as `src` value of `img` tag.

```html
<v-img :src="url" />
```

Comment: oh oops.. Thanks for pointing that out I posted the wrong code, it was kinda close. Its updated  now